# Reading a file by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, query-optimization

I have a 250Mb file to be read. And the application is multi threaded. If i allow all threads to read the file the memory starvation occurs.
I get out of memory error.

To avoid it. I want to have only one copy of the String (which is read from stream) in memory and i want all the threads to use it.

```
while (true) {
    synchronized (buffer) {
        num = is.read(buffer);
            String str = new String(buffer, 0, num);

    }
    sendToPC(str);
}
```

Basically i want to have only one copy of string when all thread completed sending, i want to read second string and so on.

Comment: @Dheeraj  are u talking about sharing each line of string from a file by multiple threads.

Comment: @Dheeraj what u want to acheive by using multiple threads.

Comment: All well and good. What's your question, then?

Comment: I am unable to keep one copy of string and push it to multiple PC's and then read next chunk and send it to multiple PC's

Comment: @Suresh. The code was written some years back, i am trying to do memory optimization. This was designed like all threads open separate channels to file and convert the byte array to string and push that string to different PC's (one thread per PC). But we are frequently getting OOM exception. So i want to tweak this workflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why multiple threads? You only have one disk and it can only go so fast. Multithreading it won't help, almost certainly. And any software design that relies on having an entire file in memory is seriously flawed in the first place.

Suppose you define your *problem?*

Comment: To make some points clear. I want to push a file to multiple computers.

Comment: @Dheeraj: Then read the file in *one thread* and use separate worker threads to push the data to the other computers.

Comment: I don't completely agree with your answer, but perhaps it depends on how it's interpreted.  In game development, there's a lot of data to load and we need to load it as fast as possible.  Granted, consoles are limited so you might not be able to do this, but on a PC it is MUCH faster to pre-load the file into memory and then to process it.  Actually, in the game engine I'm working on I'm changing my content loader to use data streams, versus accessing the file directly, so I can opt to pre-load the file given enough memory;  I don't like load times, and this is one easy way to speed them up.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is kind of late, but I think what you want here is to use the map function in the FileChannel class. Once you map a region of the file into memory, then all of your threads can read or write to that block of memory and the OS will synchronizes that memory region with the file periodically (or when you call MappedByteBuffer.load()), and if you want each thread to work with a different part of the file, then you can assign several maps each mapping a specific region of the file and just use one map per thread.

see the javadoc for [FileChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29), [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getChannel%28%29), and [MappedByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Could you directly use streams instead of completely reading the file in to memory?

Comment: No. Unfortunately now. It was written in this way. And i need to do memory optimization now. The receiver only receives string and file as parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can register all threads as callbacks in the File reading class. SO have something like an array or list of classes implementing an interface StringReaderThread which has the method processString(String input). After reading each line from the file, iterate over this array/list and call processString() on all the threads this way. Would this solve your problem?