# Spring Batch - How to achieve multi-threading/partitioning with Single large XML - StaxEventItemReader

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-batch, partitioning, stax

I am using Spring Batch 3.2 for bulk migration of data from XML to Database.

My XML contains around 140K users and I want to dump it into DB.

I do not want to proceed it in a single thread.

I tried using `TaskExecutor` but not able to succeed due to below error.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </consumerName>; expected </first>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [4814,26]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:464)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.reportWrongEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3283)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3210)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2829)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
    at org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventReaderImpl.peek(Stax2EventReaderImpl.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.stax.DefaultFragmentEventReader.nextEvent(DefaultFragmentEventReader.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.stax.DefaultFragmentEventReader.markFragmentProcessed(DefaultFragmentEventReader.java:184)
```

where `consumerName` and `first` are XML nodes.

I knew `StaxEventItemReader` is not a thread safe and multiple threads are using XML and due to that issue, there is some problem in marking fragments as processed and I am not able to get unique record as well as complete fragment to process.

Can any one suggest me how Can I use multi-threading/partitioning in my case.

What I want

- By using multi-threading, how can I make sure that each thread get unique chuck i.e (Thread 1 - fragement 1-100, Thread 2 - fragement 101-200.... so on)
- Each thread process unique chuck and dump into DB.

**My configuration**

```
<batch:job id="sampleJob">
        <batch:step id="multiThreadStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor"  throttle-limit="10">
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="itemWriter" 
                    processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" skip-limit="1500000">
                    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <!-- <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
        <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="10"/>
    </bean>  -->

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    </bean>

<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="userItem" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="userDetailUnmarshaller" />
    <property name="saveState" value="false" />
</bean>
```

**Sample XML**

```
<userItems>
     <userItem>
     <...>
     <...>
     </userItem>     
     <userItem>
     <...>
     <...>
     </userItem>
     ...
     ...
</userItems>
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7632618/1743880

Comment: I gone through that block... Is that mean, I cant achieve multi-threading in my case?

Comment: I don't think it is possible because there is not much you can do in parallel when reading a single file. I might be mistaken, that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: What if I synchronized Read() operations and parallel threads can flush data in DB? Or Can I use partitioning in this case ?