# Spring Batch -- Multi-File-Resource -- Takes same time as single Thread?

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch, partitioning

I am using Spring Batch for data migration from XML to Oracle Database.

With Single Thread execution, process takes 80-90 Mins to insert 20K users approx.

I want to reduce it to more than half but even using Multi File Resource, I am not able to achieve that.

I have a single XML to be processed so I started simply by adding

- task executor and making Reader synchronized but not able to achieve gain.

So what I am doing, I split XML into multiple XMLS and want to try with Multi File Resource. Here is the configuration.

```
<batch:job id="importJob">

        <batch:step id="step1Master">
            <batch:partition handler="handler" partitioner="partitioner" />
        </batch:step>

</batch:job>

<bean id="handler"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler">
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
        <property name="step" ref="slaveStep" />
        <property name="gridSize" value="20" />
    </bean>

    <batch:step id="slaveStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer"
                processor="processor" commit-interval="1000" skip-limit="1500000">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>


        </batch:tasklet>

    </batch:step>

    <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="300" />
        <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="partitioner"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
        scope="step">
        <property name="keyName" value="inputFile" />
        <property name="resources"
            value="file:/.../*.xml" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="processor"
        class="...Processor"
        scope="step" />

    <bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="user" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="userDetailUnmarshaller" />
        <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext[inputFile]}" />
    </bean>
```

My Single XML file contains users around 1000 and I am trying by having 20 files.

I kept commit-interval=1000 as each file has 1000 records to be insert in DB.

Do commit-interval needs to adjusted accordingly?

I am using ORACLE DB, Do I need to do any pool management there.
Current Pool of ORACLE DB configured in JBOSS
Min Pool = 100
Max Pool = 300

I see logging like

```
17:01:50,553 DEBUG [Writer] (taskExecutor-11) [UserDetailWriter] | user added
17:01:50,683 DEBUG [Writer] (taskExecutor-15) [UserDetailWriter] | user added
17:01:51,093 DEBUG [Writer] (taskExecutor-11) [UserDetailWriter] | user added
17:01:59,795 DEBUG [Writer] (taskExecutor-12) [UserDetailWriter] | user added
17:02:00,385 DEBUG [Writer] (taskExecutor-12) [UserDetailWriter] | user added
17:02:00,385 DEBUG [Writer] (taskExecutor-12) [UserDetailWriter] | user added
```

It seems multiple threads are being created but still I am not seeing any performance improvement here?

Please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Multi file resource wont work like what you thought. it will pick one by one file and delgate it to the writer one by one. thats why you would not see any performance gain. multi file resource intended to run one by one not by all at a time by mutiple threads

Comment: If this is the case than what is the advantage of parallel processing?

Answer (score -2):

go through this documentation for parallel processing

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps

Comment: I already gone through this, obviously I set up configurations by referring those only